# Symfony 2.8 two database connections

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to connect to an external database, I just need to do a simple query in one table so I think I dont need to create an new entity manager.  I believe all configurations are set up correctly but I still don't get connected to the new database. So i´m missing something but cant find what, here are my files:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
                # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
                #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
                #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3'
                #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
                #   3. Uncomment next line:
                #path: '%database_path%'

            database2:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database2_host%'
                port: '%database2_port%'
                dbname: '%database2_name%'
                user: '%database2_user%'
                password: '%database2_password%'
                charset: UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

```
parameters:
#Set_Goals Database
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: set_goals
    database_user: root
    database_password: null

#Database2 Database
    database2_host: 127.0.0.1
    database2_port: null
    database2_name: second
    database2_user: root
    database2_password: null
```

```
Repository:
public function getAccounts(){
    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection('database2');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM leme_account';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Error:
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM leme_account':

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'set_goals.leme_account' doesn't exist

set_goals database is the default connection.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I´m missing something really simple here but I´m new to Symfony and programming in general and I followed the documentation and also some related questions here but can´t make it work.

Comment: Your database2 configuration will generate a service named 'doctrine.dbal.database2_connection'. Pull it from the container and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create another entity manager

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
                # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
                #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
                #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3'
                #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
                #   3. Uncomment next line:
                #path: '%database_path%'

            database2:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database2_host%'
                port: '%database2_port%'
                dbname: '%database2_name%'
                user: '%database2_user%'
                password: '%database2_password%'
                charset: UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
            database2:
                connection: database2
```

Then in your code

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$em2 = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('database2');
```

The documentation mentions a mappings key but I don't know if it is mandatory, especially since you are using auto mapping.

Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: That will probably cause more trouble than it is worth.  The doctrine dbal connections are available as services.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I found the problem.... it was a newb mistake. I was putting my method inside the repository of the other entity. When I added directly to the controller it worked.
Thanks for your answers.